# Converting javascript hexadecimal code

Tags: javascript

I was going through some downloaded javascripts and found code is written in Hexadecimal values instead of the 'normal' js syntax. For example:

```
if (!_0x7cd2x2[_0x2dae[19]](_0x2dae[18])) {
    var _0x7cd2x8 = true;
    _0x7cd2x2[_0x2dae[21]](_0x2dae[20]);
} else {
    var _0x7cd2x8 = false;
    _0x7cd2x2[_0x2dae[21]](_0x2dae[22]);
}
;
if (_0x7cd2x2[_0x2dae[19]](_0x2dae[23])) {
    var _0x7cd2x9 = true
}
;
```

Can somebody please help me in understanding the code and how it was done.

Comment: The code has been transformed with a program to make it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in fact, the code above is 100% perfectly valid javascript. The original script has been run through an obfuscator in order to make it difficult to understand.

Most likely whichever obfuscator was used replaces variable names with numbers, prefixes them with "_" and prints the number as a hex value.

To understand the code you will need the entire sample, and a lot of patience.

Comment: I have the whole script. Is there a way I can reverse it?

Comment: Not automatically. No, Without a mapping of the hex values to their original names there is no way to know what things were called. On top of this, obfuscators often switch statements in such a way that does not break the underlying logic.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You are more than welcome :) I'm sorry it wasn't better news.